# Find vector d perpendicular to the z axis and to the vector a

Tags: vectors, analytic-geometry

> Determine the vector $\vec d$ perpendicular to the z axis and to the vector $\vec a$ = 8$\vec i$  − 15$\vec j$  + 3$\vec k$ , so that its intensity is 50 and forms an acute angle with the x axis.

---

So here is what I know:

$\vec{d} = (d_1, d_2, d_3) $

$ \vec{a} \cdot \vec{d} = 0 $

This translates into $ 8d_1 - 15d_2 + 3d_3 = 0 $

$ | \vec{d} | = 50 $ ->

$  \sqrt{d_1^2 + d_2^2 + d_3^2}=50 $

But I dont know what does it mean that vector $\vec d$  is perpendiuclar to the z axis, and that vector $\vec d$ forms an acute angle with x axis. I would be thankful for any help.

Comment: $\;d\;$ perpendicular to the $\;z\,-$ axis $\;\iff d\perp(0,0,1)\;$

Comment: As in [your previous question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4645288/89922), cosine of $\vec d$'s angle with the $x$-axis becomes $d_1$. If that angle is acute, then its cosine is positive.

Comment: Yes, I figure it out when I saw the first comment and I remmbered that it was the same as my prevoius question.  Thank you @peterwhy